# Express 4 app.locals getting a cookie value

Tags: cookies, express, express-4

Ok basically I've got Express 4 running and I want to get the value of a cookie on every page, I felt that app.locals was a good fit for this but I cannot get it grab a cookies value in app.js

I tried

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    app.locals.uid = req.cookies['uid']
}
```

However it makes it so none of my pages ever load so anyone got some experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

use res.locals (http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.locals) instead - app.locals are the same for all application, and res.locals are unique for each request